# Using where clause in Sql Server LEAD

Tags: sql-server

I'm writing a query which involves `LEAD`. I recently discovered it and made my life a lot easier. But I have a small problem

My query is this;

```
SELECT a.ActivityTypeID,acs.ActivityStatementID,
LEAD(acs.ActivityStatementID) OVER (PARTITION BY StatementCode ORDER BY a.ActualDateTime DESC) PreviousStatementID,
acs.Value as CurrentValue,
LEAD(acs.Value) OVER (PARTITION BY StatementCode ORDER BY a.ActualDateTime DESC) as Prev
FROM ActivityStatement acs 
   INNER JOIN Activity a on a.ActivityID = acs.ActivityID
WHERE a.CustomerID = 128077
and a.TenantID = 19
and a.ActualDateTime IS NOT NULL
```

And a line in my query result is this

```
+----------------+---------------------+---------------------+--------------+------+
| ActivityTypeID | ActivityStatementID | PreviousStatementID | CurrentValue | Prev |
+----------------+---------------------+---------------------+--------------+------+
| 397            | 849433              | 849609              | A            | A    |
+----------------+---------------------+---------------------+--------------+------+
```

But when I check the details of the returning ID's as this

```
select acs.activitystatementid,a.ActivityTypeID,a.ActualDateTime from ActivityStatement acs
  inner join Activity a on a.ActivityID = acs.ActivityID
  where acs.ActivityStatementID IN (849433,849609)
  and a.CustomerID = 128077
```

I see that `ActivityTypeID` of records are not the same

```
+---------------------+----------------+-------------------------+
| activitystatementid | activitytypeid | ActualDateTime          |
+---------------------+----------------+-------------------------+
| 849433              | 397            | 2018-05-21 11:59:37.000 |
+---------------------+----------------+-------------------------+
| 849609              | 396            | 2018-05-21 11:59:05.000 |
+---------------------+----------------+-------------------------+
```

Basically, I want to make sure in my first query that `LEAD` is comparing only records with same `ActivityTypeID` but I couldn't find how to do it.

Sql Server Version is Sql Server 2016(SP1-CU3)

Comment: `LEAD` returns the value of the *next*, as determined by `ORDER BY`, row within a subset of data, defined by the `PARTITION BY` clause. Isn't this what you want?

Comment: PARTITION BY ActivityTypeID

Comment: PARTITION BY ActivityTypeID is causing same activity results. I want to compare the result of a activity with the previous activity of same type. Same activityType,different activity ids, different actualdatetimes. Statement codes are same between activities.

Comment: Things that you want the *same* between rows to be considered together goes in your `PARTITION BY` clause. If you want the same `StatementCode` and `ActivityTypeID` values, then you need both in the `PARTITION BY`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "...comparing only records with same ActivityTypeID".

The key to accomplishing this is the additional `, ActivityId` in the `PARTITION BY` clause.

```
SELECT a.ActivityTypeID,acs.ActivityStatementID,
LEAD(acs.ActivityStatementID) OVER (PARTITION BY StatementCode, ActivityId ORDER BY a.ActualDateTime DESC) PreviousStatementID,
acs.Value as CurrentValue,
LEAD(acs.Value) OVER (PARTITION BY StatementCode, ActivityId ORDER BY a.ActualDateTime DESC) as Prev
FROM ActivityStatement acs 
   INNER JOIN Activity a on a.ActivityID = acs.ActivityID
WHERE a.CustomerID = 128077
and a.TenantID = 19
and a.ActualDateTime IS NOT NULL
```